# Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, hql

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: cspName

```
st.append("SELECT customers.name,sum(csp.cspValue) as TotalMoney ");
            st.append("from Account as account ");
            st.append("left join account.CSPFields as csp with ((account.accountID=csp.id) and  (csp.cspName = 'Target')) ");
            st.append("left join Customers as customers");
            st.append("with account.customerExec.id=customers.id ");
st.append("where (account.accountDate between :startDate and :endDate) ");
            st.append("and (account.accountBatch.id in (:acIDs)) ");
            st.append("group by customers.name");
```

CSPFields is object of map in Account class. cspName is key in map collection.

Answer (score 0):

[HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) is case sensitive where objects are concerned, is your ACCOUNT entity really all upper case? It might help if you posted your Customer and ACCOUNT entity.

Answer (score 0):

could you try using elements(account.CSPFields). That should do the trick.